# Trouble producing cobertura coverage

Tags: maven, code-coverage, cobertura

My code contains tests and those tests run fine upon `mvn clean install`

I have included a cobertura prlugin in order to produce the reports as

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>cobertura</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

At the end, HTML is produced in the `target` as expected. `index.html` shows all classes and packages but ... no coverage information (0% coverage for all)

If i export coverage via `IntelliJ` it shows coverage appropriately. Is my setup missing something obvious?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you're trying to execute `cobertura` in the `clean` phase of the project.

According to the documentation, Cobertura uses its own lifecycle: http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html

Please remove the `<phase>clean</phase>` from your `execution` configuration and try again.

Further references here:

- [How do I configure when cobertura tests run in maven-cobertura-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449283/how-do-i-configure-when-cobertura-tests-run-in-maven-cobertura-plugin)
- http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: It seems that removing the `<phase>clean</phase>` stops report from being produced alltogether. When i tried different phases (`install`, `package`) result is the same as with `clean`