# how to run cobertura during mvn install phase

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, cobertura

I have the following plugin defined for cobertura as follows. I have to run mvn cobertura:cobertura to get the code coverage report. How to edit the pom so that mvn install  runs the cobertura ?

```
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cobertura have its own lifecycle. It executes all goals which cobertura coverage reporting need in specific order.
See :
[How do I configure when cobertura tests run in maven-cobertura-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449283/how-do-i-configure-when-cobertura-tests-run-in-maven-cobertura-plugin)

Only option would be to configure cobertura goals to be executed in default lifecycle phases, but since report generation goal is  assumed to be run as Maven report:

> http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html

is is IMO impossible to be done in easy way (or to be done at all).